# Meaning of proper antichain

Tags: combinatorics, definition

I saw this [sequence](http://oeis.org/A051303) on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which describe the number of 3-element proper antichains of an n-element set.

What does it mean to be a 3-element proper antichain of an n-element set? Suppose the set is $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. A $3$-element antichain could be something like $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,4\}$, where any two sets are incomparable. Now what does "proper" mean?

Comment: I'm also confused by this.  I googled 'proper antichain' and got this document, which seems relevant: 

http://oeis.org/A056782/a056782.pdf